# get mysql time zone in php

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

how do i get the srver time zone exept of the date("e") function i need somthing that will check the os time zone and not depends on the php ini and stuff like that...

i need this becouse i need to know the mysql time zone

if i run a query for select global_time_zone i got the result "system" and i need a result like "amrica/new york"

Answer (score 1):

If it's a linux server you could do

```
$timezone = file_get_contents('/etc/timezone');
```

I don't know of any native php functions that would do this, nor do I really see the point? What's wrong with getting the ini specified timezone (which defaults to the server timezone)?